# group by extract sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to Group by a few columns including an extract column for month and year.
The sql keeps returning group by the original date column.  How can I extract date to Month and year and then group on this column.  Below is my full sql:

```
select Name,
extract(month from fill_Date) as Month,
extract(year from fill_Date) as Year, 
sum(quantity)
from Table A
group by Name,fill_Date
```

Comment: Put the `extract(Month from fill_Date), extract(year from fill_Date)` in the `Group By` instead of the `fill_Date`.

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the `extract()` calls in the group-by clause:

```
select Name,
  extract(month from fill_Date) as Month,
  extract(year from fill_Date) as Year, 
  sum(quantity)
from TableA
group by Name,
  extract(month from fill_Date),
  extract(year from fill_Date)
```

Or use a subquery (inline view) or CTE to extract the value, then use the column aliases for the grouping - you can't refer to a column alias in the same level of query as it's defined, but the subquery means it *isn't* the same level:

```
select Name,
  Month,
  Year,
  sum(quantity)
from (
  select Name,
    extract(month from fill_Date) as Month,
    extract(year from fill_Date) as Year, 
    quantity
  from TableA
)
group by Name,
  Month,
  Year
```

---

You don't have to extract the year and month seperately, though you may want to of course. If your goal is just to group by year/month combinations, you can use the `trunc()` function to make it ignore the day and any time part of the column value, and group by that instead:

```
select Name,
  to_char(trunc(fill_Date, 'MM'), 'MM YYYY') as month,
  sum(quantity)
from TableA
group by Name,
  trunc(fill_Date, 'MM')
```

The `trunc(fill_Date, 'MM')` gives you midnight on the first day of the month. Using `to_char()` in the select list formats that to only show the month and year, though now in a single column, and as a string rather than two numbers. You can use `to_char()` in the group-by but you don't need to.